Permission Denied Terminal Error after opening
I get the following prompt after opening Terminal and it won't react to any commands.
/Users/louis/.zprofile:13: permission denied: /Users/louis/.zprofile
I really appreciate any help.
I already gave Terminal Full Disk Access.

Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; Superuser and (assuming you're on macOS) Ask Different are better places for things like this. Before asking, search for previous relevant questions. Also, my guess is that the real problem is that whatever's on line 13 of your .zprofile is trying to do something bad, and permissions are protecting you from that bad thing happening. But without knowing what's actually in your .zprofile (particularly line 13) that's just a guess.

Thanks bro, I´ll ask on Ask Different then. I could not find any previous questions that answered mine. It happened right after i installed HomeBrew. And Terminal also does not react to any commands. If you have any idea for me to fix it, let me know. Thanks for your answer

As I said, without knowing what's in your .zprofile, I can only guess. So what's in /Users/louis/.zprofile?
